# Запрос для получение даты в нормальном формате

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть база, там дата хранится в таком состоянии - **2014-10-21**.

Как сделать SQL-запрос, чтобы получить дату в нормальном состоянии, т.е. 21.10.2014?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = "2014-10-21";
$code = explode("-",$date);
echo $code[2].'.'.$code[1].'.'.$code[0];
```

А если так попробовать?
А вообще дату в базе обычно хранят в секундах с 1970 года, а при выборке формируют как хотят

Comment: Спасибо класс. Хранить в секундах не прикольно, потому что туда надо ее еще и записывать. Хотя надо написать конструктор, который конвертирует туда-сюда дату.

Comment: Тогда я вам советую почитать про тип TIMESTAMP в MySQL.  
Проблема в том, если у вас на сайте имеется вывод дат в различной форме или нужно посчитать какую-то разницу, то нужно хранить время в секундах. В вашем же случае вы будите всегда конвертировать, это лишние действия.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @Flur, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.